# Puppeteer waitForSelector with wildcards

Tags: puppeteer, wildcard

I'm running into an issue while using node js puppeteer(https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to do some web scraping.
I have a selector looking like this
#__BVID__119 > div > div.d-flex.mt-10.justify-content-md-between > div:nth-child(2) > label > span
The problem is, the id after **BVID** changes dynamically.
How can I use any wildcards there?
I tried stuff like this:
await page.waitForSelector("#[contains(.,'BVID')] > div > div.d-flex.mt-10.justify-content-md-between > div:nth-child(2) > label > span")
and:
await page.$x("[contains(., '> div > div.d-flex.mt-10.justify-content-md-between > div:nth-child(2) > label > spa')]");
I'm happy about any tipps!
Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

patpatwithhat, hi!

You can locate element by id partially using selector like this `div[id^="val"]` where:

- *div* - tag of the element.
- *"val"* - part of the element's id.

It would be great if you could provide a link for this web page to find a final solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Here is the website https://xdai.unique.one/create/erc721, but I guess, you won't be able to enter it without Metamask.
I'll try your solution later!

Comment: @patpatwithhat, yes, I don't know how to login. Btw could you make a screenshot of that element from DevTools?

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir, but not needed! I already figured it out!

Comment: @patpatwithhat,
It would be great if you could mark my answer as a correct)